# Why does my enterbutton refresh my page?

Tags: jquery, reload, enter

Here is my Jquery code for my "site".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#val').click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("input[name=message]").val();
    $('#messages').append("<p>"+toAdd+"</p>");
    $('#messages').val(""); //remove text in textbox//  
});

$('#kor').click(function() {
var random = Math.floor((Math.random()*$("#messages>p").length));

alert($("#messages>p").eq(random).text());
});
});
```

I got a textbox and when pressing "#val" it adds whats in the text box to a "pool" where it sooner will randomly choose something in the pool.

My problem is when hitting the Enter key, my page reload. I would like to bind my enter button to "#val" or disable it. Cause pressing enter and reload page is pretty annoying.

Comment: Because the input is in a form, and when hitting enter in an input inside a form, the form submits. You have to prevent the form.submit

Comment: If you provide HTML we can tell you how to prevent submission of a form

Answer (score 2):

As adeneo said, you have to prevent the default behaviour of the Enter key, which is submitting the form. But he didn't say how :) Here's how :

```
$('#val').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   /* some other stuff */
})
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. Been stuck on this problem a long time, I appreciate it! :)